# Instances of javafx.scene.Cursor cannot be created by FXML loader

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

I am trying to create pane using FXML.But there is an error printed out by the program that says "Instances of javafx.scene.Cursor cannot be created by FXML loader ".[Here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0BfDK.png)

Comment: Post the complete FXML in your question (as text, [not as an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)). Does the application run despite the netbeans message? If not, what exception is generated?

Comment: Some ways of referencing objects / creating objects do not seem to be recognized by Netbeans. You can simply ignore this error.

Comment: @James_D: there is no exeption, as i said the error is printed out by the program , and yes my application run normally

Comment: Then as others have said, you can ignore this error message.

Comment: Any one found the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed this, too. I think it's a bug in NetBeans.
I haven't had the time yet to file an issue. Feel free to do so: https://netbeans.org/community/issues.html